# display graph in jqplot using two variables from a database

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, graph, jqplot

I'm new to jqplot and I have been trying to display a graph with the dates (x axis) and values(y axis) from a database.
I managed to save the dates and values into a nice string ( all the data is separated by commas and in the good order) but when I call  $.jqplot('chart1', [**total1**], it does not work! :(
I have tried everything and I'm running out of ideas and hope. 
any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.
regards from a desperate newbie

```
    <?php

        $conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
        mysql_select_db($database);

 $MenuSelection = $_POST['dropDownMenu'];// select field from dropdownmenu   
        $conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
        mysql_select_db($database);

 $sql = "SELECT date," . $MenuSelection . " FROM errorscounted where date       between '$CurrentDate' and '$FinalDate'";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            $data = array();
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }

            mysql_free_result($result);

    mysql_close();
    ?>

<script type="text/javascript" >

 $(document).ready(function () {
var total1 = "";

// create a for loop to get dates and values and save them in a string
<?php for ($x = 0; $x <= 4; $x++) { ?>
var line1 = [['<?php echo $data[$x]['date'] ?>',
<?php echo $data[$x][$myvalue] ?>], ];

// concatenated the string and seperated the dates and values by a comma
total1 = total1.concat(line1) + ",";
    <?php } ?>
//delete the last comma
 total1 = total1.substring(0, total1.length - 1);

// an alert that shows that all the data was saved correctly
 alert(total1); 

 var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [total1], {
animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
title: 'Number of errors from <?php echo $_POST['dateStart'] ?> to <?php echo $_POST['dateEnd'] ?> for <?php echo $_POST['dropDownMenu'] ?> ',
                            seriesDefaults: {
                                pointLabels: {show: true}
                            },
                            axesDefaults: {
                                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                                tickOptions: {
                                    angle: -30,
                                    fontSize: '10pt'
                                }
                            },
                            axes: {
                                xaxis: {
                                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                                    // renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                                    tickOptions: {
                                    }
                                },
                                yaxis: {
                                    tickOptions: {
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            highlighter: {
                                show: false,
                                sizeAdjust: 7.5
                            },
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks to one of my coworkers i have finally solved my problem! :)

I was giving jqplot a string but it needed an array! here's my very simple solution. hope it will help someone!
Here's my code working 100% bullet proof

```
            <script type="text/javascript" >

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var total1 = [];

 // create a for loop to get dates and values and save them in a string
<?php
$j = count($data);
for ($x = 0; $x < $j; $x++) {
    ?>

                        var line1 = ['<?php echo $data[$x]['date'] ?>',<?php echo $data[$x][$myvalue] ?>];
                        total1.push(line1);
<?php } ?>
                    // alert(total1);
                    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [total1], {
                        animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
                        title: 'Number of errors from <?php echo $_POST['dateStart'] ?> to <?php echo $_POST['dateEnd'] ?> for <?php echo $_POST['dropDownMenu'] ?> ',
                        seriesDefaults: {
                            pointLabels: {show: true}
                        },
                        axesDefaults: {
                            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                            tickOptions: {
                                angle: -30,
                                fontSize: '10pt'
                            }
                        },
                        axes: {
                            xaxis: {
                                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                                //renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                                tickOptions: {
                                }
                            },
                            yaxis: {min: 0,
                            }
                        },
                        highlighter: {
                        },
                    });
                });
            </script>
```